# Flutter: Stepper is not scrolling when added inside ListView

Tags: dart, flutter

I have ListView which contains - 
1. Banner Image
2. Container with some Text
3. Container with Some more Text
4. Container consist of Stepper.

I'm unable to scroll, When I try to scroll while taping the Stepper area. And even last step of stepper goes out of screen.

Adding CODE -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          new MyContents(),
          new MyContents(),
          new MyContents(),
          new MyContents(),
          new SimpleWidget(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyContents extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
            child: new Card(
              child: new Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Text(
                    "Cards Content Cards ContentCards Content Cards Content Cards ContentCards Content Cards Content Cards Content "
                  ),
                  new Text(
                    "Cards Content Cards ContentCards Content Cards Content Cards ContentCards Content Cards Content Cards Content "
                  ),
                  new Text(
                    "Cards Content Cards ContentCards Content Cards Content Cards ContentCards Content Cards Content Cards Content "
                  ),
                  new Text(
                    "Cards Content Cards ContentCards Content Cards Content Cards ContentCards Content Cards Content Cards Content "
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            );
  }
}




class SimpleWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  SimpleWidgetState createState() => new SimpleWidgetState();
}

class SimpleWidgetState extends State<SimpleWidget> {
  int stepCounter = 0;
  List<Step> steps = [
    new Step(
      title:new Text("Step One"),
      content: new Text("This is the first step"),
      isActive: true,
    ),
    new Step(
      title:new Text("Step Two"),
      content: new Text("This is the second step"),
      isActive: true,
    ),
    new Step(
      title:new Text("Step Three"),
      content: new Wrap(
                  spacing: 8.0, // gap between adjacent chips
                  runSpacing: 4.0, // gap between lines
                  direction: Axis.horizontal, // main axis (rows or columns)
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Chip(
                      label: new Text('Chips11')
                    ),new Chip(
                      label: new Text('Chips12')
                    ),new Chip(
                      label: new Text('Chips13')
                    ),new Chip(
                      label: new Text('Chips14')
                    ),new Chip(
                      label: new Text('Chips15')
                    ),new Chip(
                      label: new Text('Chips16')
                    )
                  ],
              ),
      state: StepState.editing,
      isActive: true,
    ),
    new Step(
      title: new Text("Step Four"),
      content: new Text("This is the fourth step"),
      isActive: true,
    ),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      child: new Stepper(
        currentStep: this.stepCounter,
        steps: steps,
        type: StepperType.vertical,
        onStepTapped: (step) {
          setState(() {
            stepCounter = step;
          });
        },
        onStepCancel: () {
          setState(() {
            stepCounter > 0 ? stepCounter -= 1 : stepCounter = 0;
          });
        },
        onStepContinue: () {
          setState(() {
            stepCounter < steps.length - 1 ? stepCounter += 1 : stepCounter = 0;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Try to Scroll tapping Stepper area. Its not working.

Comment: Could you provide some code example?

Comment: Edited post, Check it out !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution. Stepper is already scroll-able widget, And as i was adding Stepper inside ListView it was becoming Scrollable widget inside another Scrollable widget.

@FunMiles from Gitter suggested to use [NestedScrollView](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/NestedScrollView-class.html) widget instead of ListView & that solved my prob.

```
class TestAppHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  TestAppHomePageState createState() => new TestAppHomePageState();
}

class TestAppHomePageState extends State<TestAppHomePage>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Test Title'),
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: new NestedScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            new SliverList(
              delegate:new SliverChildListDelegate(<Widget>[
                    new MyContents(),
                    new MyContents(),
                    new MyContents(),
                    new MyContents(),
              ]),
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: new SimpleWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Do you know, how can i put a scrollbar insider stepper widget. i am using a column

Answer (score 32):

If the stepper is contained within another scrollable, you can set stepper physics to ClampingScrollPhysics

```
Stepper(physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(), //remaing stepper code
```

in your case you are using listview which is scrollable, by setting stepper physics to **ClampingScrollPhysics()** the parent widget (listview) will have the controller of stepper scroll

Edit:
as @asubanovsky stated in the comment, you can use `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` as well to be more precise for removing the scroll behavior of the current widget and let the parent widget handle it

Comment: If the stepper has a a scrollable widget as its parent, we can apply NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() to its physics and let the scroll being handled by the parent widget.

Comment: has anybody tried this in flutter web? for me it seems like this solution is not working for flutter web, possibly also related to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34174